# Good way to fetch XML from a remote URL, convert it to HTML and display it in a ASP.NET-page

Tags: .net, asp.net

The use case I want to achive is.

```
1. Fetch XML from a remote URL.
2. Convert it to HTML using XSLT
3. Insert the generated HTML at a position in my ASP.NET web forms page.
```

Alternative on the above, if *1* returns a 404:

```
2. Generate HTML which display an error message to the user.
```

Only step 3 is left as I've completed 1-2. As there are logic for handling the two execution paths and performing the XSLT-transformation I thought it would be suitable to keep it in the code-behind file.

**What's a good, clean way of inserting generated HTML at a position in my ASP.NET web forms page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the HTML as a string, you can add a literal to your web form:

```
<asp:Literal id="litHtml" runat="server" />
```

and set its value in your code behind:

```
litHtml.Text = "Your HTML";
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Use XmlDocument.Load  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)

2/3- use A asp:Xml server control ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zsyhz5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) with a tranformsource ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xml.transformsource%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) , and initialize youXmlServerControl.Document ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xml.document%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) with the XmlDocument from 1/

Ask if i'm not clear.